# How to count particular types of characters in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to count how many lowercase characters occur in one cell, and then how many uppercase characters occur and also how many special characters occur. How can I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following four User Defined Functions:

```
Public Function LowC(r As Range) As Long
    Dim s As String, ch As String
    Dim IAmTheCount As Long, L As Long
    s = r.Text
    IAmTheCount = 0
    For L = 1 To Len(s)
        If Mid(s, L, 1) Like "[a-z]" Then
            IAmTheCount = IAmTheCount + 1
        End If
    Next L
    LowC = IAmTheCount
End Function

Public Function HighC(r As Range) As Long
    Dim s As String, ch As String
    Dim IAmTheCount As Long, L As Long
    s = r.Text
    IAmTheCount = 0
    For L = 1 To Len(s)
        If Mid(s, L, 1) Like "[A-Z]" Then
            IAmTheCount = IAmTheCount + 1
        End If
    Next L
    HighC = IAmTheCount
End Function

Public Function NumC(r As Range) As Long
    Dim s As String, ch As String
    Dim IAmTheCount As Long, L As Long
    s = r.Text
    IAmTheCount = 0
    For L = 1 To Len(s)
        If Mid(s, L, 1) Like "[0-9]" Then
            IAmTheCount = IAmTheCount + 1
        End If
    Next L
    NumC = IAmTheCount
End Function

Public Function OtherC(r As Range) As Long
    OtherC = Len(r.Text) - LowC(r) - HighC(r) - NumC(r)
End Function
```

They will return the number of upper case, lowercase, numeric, and other characters in a **single** cell.

Comment: That's brilliant, Gary. I actually saw one of your forum posts this afternoon asking a similar question, I think it was dated quite some time ago. Small world. Anyway, if anybody stumbles across this, use this link to create a User Defined Function: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-User-Defined-Function-in-Microsoft-Excel

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with Excel functions, although VBA seems a lot simpler to me.

With Excel Functions:

Upper Case Count:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")),1)>="A")*(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")),1)<="Z")*EXACT(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")),1),UPPER(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")),1))))
```

Lower Case Count

```
SUMPRODUCT((MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")),1)>="A")*(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")),1)<="Z")*EXACT(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")),1),LOWER(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")),1))))
```

Numbers Count

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(-MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")),1)))
```

Specials Count

```
=LEN(A1)-SUM(SUMPRODUCT((MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")),1)>="A")*(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")),1)<="Z")*EXACT(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")),1),UPPER(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")),1)))),SUMPRODUCT((MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")),1)>="A")*(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")),1)<="Z")*EXACT(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")),1),LOWER(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")),1)))),SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(-MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:99")),1))))
```